# Two way synchronization with SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Can I use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) to create a two-way synchronization between tables in two different databases? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

If it is possible, then how do I handle synchronization conflicts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that it is definitely possible.  I am not sure that it would be the best option and any synchronization conflicts will need to be handled explicitly by your programming.  I would consult MSDN first and read up on High availability solutions and Disaster Recovery before I went any further.
[MSDN High Availability Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202.aspx)

[Disaster Recovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178094.aspx)

[Sql Server Installation Planning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500442.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use SQL Server Integration
>   Services (SSIS) to create a two-way
>   synchronization between tables in two
>   different databases? I am using SQL
>   Server 2008 R2.

SSIS is a framework for doing ETL / Data Load jobs. What they do is your problem, not SSIS. So, you CAN do it, but YOU have to do it. 2 way sync is definitely challenging and not a standard ETL thing.

> If it is possible, then how do I
>   handle synchronization conflicts?

In whatever way you decide to handle them, which will be determined by how you MUST handle them per logic. SOme fields just are last entry wins. Some need elaborate logic. 2 way sync is challenging, and this needs to be determined by the programmer / architect on a case by case basis.